# I staged everything, then ran `git -rf rm .` How can I recover my files?

Tags: git, git-rm

Dumb rookie mistake. Initialize a git repository in /usr/local/Library.

```
git init
git add -A
```

Whoops, don't want to commit all those files

```
git rm -rf .
ls # EMPTY
```

Didn't do an initial commit, so `git reset HEAD` doesn't work. Is there a way to recover the contents of my /usr/local/Library directory?

Comment: What a mess... Git won't be of much help, at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it seems like you're out of luck.

If you're on OS X or Linux try looking in the .git folder with this command:

`find .git -type f`

Comment: *If you're on OS X or Linux [...]* `/usr/local/Library` indicates that the OP is on Mac OS X.

Comment: I wrote it that way because you want to try and write answers that will be helpful to others who come along looking for the answer as well.